Why is sorting a table (loaded with random data) faster than actually sorting random data?
I want to run a benchmark of sorting random records using external merge sort algorithm on Postgresql. So I tried the following 2 ways (one right after another, keeping all parameters/configurations same):
Attempt 1:
CREATE TABLE test(id BIGINT, name varchar(200));
INSERT INTO test (id,name) SELECT (random() * 1000000), concat(CONCAT(md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text))) FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) as t;

explain analyze select * from test order by id, name;
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=41486.43..63526.06 rows=188898 width=426) (actual time=76.477..207.253 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=40486.40..40722.52 rows=94449 width=426) (actual time=73.418..101.593 rows=333333 loops=3)
         Sort Key: id, name
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 29744kB
         Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 26008kB
         Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 25512kB
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..14278.49 rows=94449 width=426) (actual time=0.011..20.945 rows=333333 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 2.820 ms
 Execution Time: 227.090 ms
(11 rows)


Attempt 2:
explain analyze SELECT (random() * 1000000) as id, concat(CONCAT(md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text))) as name
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) as t order by id, name;
                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=194348.85..196848.85 rows=1000000 width=40) (actual time=1707.086..1768.986 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   Sort Key: ((random() * '1000000'::double precision)), (concat(concat(md5((random())::text), md5((random())::text))))
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 81256kB
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series t  (cost=0.00..40000.00 rows=1000000 width=40) (actual time=55.734..1388.681 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.191 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 3
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.338 ms (Deform 0.000 ms), Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.497 ms, Emission 11.837 ms, Total 12.672 ms
 Execution Time: 1841.843 ms
(10 rows)

Can someone explain to me, why sorting randomly generated data is slower than sorting the similar random data from the disk?
I re-ran both the queries with max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0; the latency of the first query dropped to 360ms, while as expected, the second query hadn't budged.


Can someone explain to me, why sorting randomly generated data is slower than sorting the similar random data from the disk?

This takes time:
SELECT (random() * 1000000), concat(CONCAT(md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text))) FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) as t;

In your first test, you're not measuring that time because you've already persisted the results to disk. Your EXPLAIN ANALYZE happens after the fact, and is measuring just the sorting of the values themselves. In your second test, you're also measuring the generation of the random values before they become sorted, so that of course should take longer.
How long does the above expression take to run on its own?

True, it gives,
`                                                             QUERY PLAN
Function Scan on generate_series t  (cost=0.00..40000.00 rows=1000000 width=40) (actual time=42.229..1350.037 rows=1000000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 1.340 ms
Execution Time: 1367.411 ms
(3 rows)`

@RohanDvivedi Cool, that makes sense then. Cheers!

The faster query can use parallel processing. The query that selects from generate_series() cannot use parallel processing, since the function has to run on a single backend.  Running with three processes makes processing faster.  The execution time for the second query is more than three times as long, but that may be a coincidence.  Try running the fast query with max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0 to disable parallelism and see if the performance difference is still large.

I re-ran both the queries with max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0; the latency of the first query dropped to 360 ms, while as expected, the second query hadn't budged.
